Variance of sum of dependent indicators
This is my first time posting on this website so please let me know if I'm not following the rules. I've been stumped on this problem for a while and after consulting AI to no avail, I'd be happy to receive someone's help. The problem is as follows:
There are $n$ elves and $2n$  humans sitting around a table. The positions of all creatures are distributed uniformly on the circle. An elf will be satisfied with their position only if they are sitting next to an elf on both sides. What is the variance of $Y$, the number of satisfied elves overall?
My attempt was to define indicators $I_1, \dots I_n$ depicting whether each respective elf sitting around the table is satisfied, such that $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n I_i$. Then $\text{Var}(Y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(I_i) + \sum_{i\neq j} \text{Cov}(I_i, I_j)$. The individual probability that $I_i=1$ is $\frac{n-1}{3n-1} \cdot \frac{n-2}{3n-2}$ which we can derive its unconditional variance from. However, I'm stumped computing the covariance as I'm sure that the dependence between the indicators is complicated, and computing $\mathbb{E}(I_i I_j) = P(I_i = I_j = 1)$ seems to be difficult to compute, and seems to depend on how far $i$ is from $j$.
I'd be extremely grateful if someone could help, this problem has stumped me for days!

Welcome on MSE. I think it would be easier to consider $I_1,\dots,I_{3n}$ (one for each creature around the table), such that $I_k=1$ if and only if the $k$-th creature is a satisfied elf. For the covariances, you'll need to consider three cases: if $i$ and $j$ are neighbors, if $i$ and $j$ are one seat appart, and if $i$  and $j$ are more than two seats appart.

So I ended up solving the question, the solution is pretty ugly but if anyone's interested (probably not):
To compute $\text{Cov}(I_i, I_j)$, we have to compute $P(I_i=I_j=1)$. To do this it is necessary to divide the problem into different possible events and use the law of total probability to compute the final value.
$P$(elves $i$ and $j$ are happy $\vert$ they are neighbors) = $\frac{{n-2 \choose {2}}2(3n-4)!}{2(3n-2)!}$ as there are $2(3n-2)!$ ways to order the elves such that $i,j$ are neighbors. For the numerator we have to choose 2 out of $n-2$ elves to be next to them on either side and other than those two elves, all other creatures can be in any order.
$P$(elves $i$ and $j$ are neighbors) = $\frac{2}{3n-1}$ as $j$ has 2 spots next to $i$ out of $3n-1$.
$P$(elves $i$ and $j$ are happy $\vert$ there is one seat between them) = $\frac{{n-2 \choose 3}3!(3n-5)!}{2(3n-2)!}$ as once again there are $2(3n-2)!$ ways to order all creatures such that $i$ and $j$ have a seat between them. For the numerator, given they have a seat between them there must be two elves on each of their sides and one elf between them, meaning we must choose 3 out of $n-2$ elves in any order. All other $3n-5$ creatures can be ordered in any order.
$P$(there is one seat between elves $i$ and $j$) = $\frac{2}{3n-1}$ as $j$ has 2 spots at distance 2 from $i$, out of $3n-1$.
$P$(elves $i$ and $j$ are happy $\vert$ their distance is $>2$) = $\frac{{n-2 \choose 4}4!(3n-6)!}{(3n-5)(3n-2)!}$. There are 4 elves that need to be placed on both sides of $i$ and $j$ in any order, hence the ${n-2 \choose 4}4!$ all creatures except the given 6 can be placed anywhere in all the $(3n-6)!$ remaining places. This results in the numerator. For the denominator, there are 5 places that $j$ can't be placed given $i$'s position, meaning there are $3n-5$ options for $j$. For all other $(3n-2)!$ creatures, they can be placed in any order, explaining the denominator of $(3n-5)(3n-2)!$.
$P$(their distance is $>2$) = $\frac{3n-5}{3n-1}$ for similar reasons.
Overall we can use all that information to apply the law of total probability:
$$P(I_i = I_j = 1) = \frac{2}{3n-1}\cdot \frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{(3n-2)(3n-3)} + \frac{2}{3n-1}\cdot \frac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)}{(3n-2)(3n-3)(3n-4)} + \frac{3n-5}{3n-1}\cdot \frac{(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)}{(3n-2)(3n-3)(3n-4)(3n-5)}$$
Using this value which we can denote as $p_2$ together with $p_1 = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{(3n-1)(3n-2)}$ which I explained in the question, we can finally get that:
$$\text{Var}(Y) = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(I_i) + \sum_{i \neq j} \text{Cov}(I_i, I_j) = np_1(1-p_1) + n(n-1)(p_2-p_1^2)$$
